# ORA-01031: insufficient privileges when inserting via dblink

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, privileges, dblink, ora-01031

This works:

```
(connect to some_db)
INSERT INTO some_schema.some_table(id) VALUES (some_schema.some_table.nextval);
```

THis works too:

```
(connect to some_other_db)
SELECT some_schema.some_table.nextval@some_db FROM DUAL;
```

This does not work:

```
(connect to some_other_db)
INSERT INTO some_schema.some_table@some_db(id) VALUES (some_schema.some_table.nextval@some_db);
```

The error I get is `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges ORA-02063: preceding line from SOME_DB`. The insert privilege for some_schema.some_table is granted through a default role.

What could be the problem here?

**Update:** adding `select` right for the table made the remote query work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insert in the local database the insert privilege is sufficient, if you insert into the remote database, you need select and the inset privilege as it will do a select during the parse phase.